# Regular Expression to return number without coma

Tags: regex

I have to extract a number formatted xx,xxx.xx in a different format - xxxxx.xx by applying a regular expression. In other words, I have to remove the comma from the number in the final capture group.

I am not quite sure if it's possible to achieve only with the regular expression and without writing specific code to split and join at these values.

Here is the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y7SojG/1/).

This is the part of input string:

`AMT    :   EGP  3,000.00`

My current regex is `AMT\s*:\s*EGP\s*(\d*,\d*.\d*)`, which basically retreives `3,000.00`.

I'm expecting to have `3000.00` in final capture group.

Comment: What tool or language are you using?

Comment: These regular expressions are part of larger-scale text parser developed specifically for our company. They are injected via spring to the Java application and applied in the backend without my control.

Comment: Can you access 2 capturing groups in the backend? See https://regex101.com/r/NUs5of/1

Comment: Hello - no way to do that, unfortunately. Seems like it`s not possible to achieve this with solely relying on regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

Since the OP doesn't want to capture and replace, the following can be done:

`AMT\s*:\s*EGP\s*(\d*),(\d*.\d*)`

The expected data is now part of the two capturing groups, and can be accessed by concatenating them: `\1\2`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y7SojG/3)

---

You can capture everything other than the `,` in two groups, and then replace:

1. Capture with:
   `(AMT\s*:\s*EGP\s*\d*),(\d*.\d*)`
2. Replace with: `\1\2`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y7SojG/2)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input! Unfortunately, I can only apply one-liner regular expression, in other words, I can`t do it in 2 stages

Comment: These are not two regular expressions. Capture followed by replace is a common phenomenon.

Comment: Also, I don't think you can get the complete thing in one group, since you want to skip the comma that comes in between the expected data. At best, there will still be two groups.

Comment: Yes, I`m afraid this might be the case - the value 3000.00 would have to be in one group, and it doesn`t seem feasible by only applying regular expressions.

Comment: The two solutions I offered is the best regex can do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AMT\s*:\s*EGP\s*\K\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?
```

[Here is Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y7SojG/4)

After find the match, do something like: `Mystring.Replac(",", "")`

Comment: Hi, no question it can be done by using any of the replace functions. Sadly, I can`t use any code as the regex is injected into back-end which I can`t access/modify in any way.